# User's devices listed as ineligible when identical devices work

Tags: android, google-play

I've come across a weird bug with my app on Google Play. There is a **single user whose 3 devices are shown as ineligible for to download my app** [image 1]

However:

1. The Google Play developer console shows my device as having 0 excluded devices [image 2]
2. I have had multiple people test on identical devices (with the same mobile carrier and a variety of Android 6.0 and up OS versions) to those that were shown as ineligible, and they **can't replicate the issue**.
3. Worth noting that the user is located in EN-US and we are available there. Additionally, her devices all shipped with at a minimum Android 6.0 and our minimum supported OS version is 4.0.

We do have a couple hypotheses/possible directions to look:

1. Elsewhere we've seen variants of this problem solved by changing
   various `<uses-permission>` and `<uses-feature>` parameters in the app
   manifest, however, since we can't replicate the problem - we don't
   have any certainty on which, if any, of the permissions we're using
   are problematic
2. It's possible that this particular person has some
   macro-level phone/account/play settings that wholesale prevent app
   installation of apps using certain features/permissions. However,
   don't know where to begin with that or if it really is possible in a
   meaningful way.
3. It's possible that the permissions in our manifest (at the end of this post) may be causing problems (note that we not use any  tags, only feature use requirements would be implied)

Any **help here would be extremely valuable**, as we've tested and researched quite a bit and are at a loss for what could be happening.

[Image 1]

[image]

[Image 2]

[image]

[AndroidManifest.xml]

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1014" android:versionName="1.01" package="[package_name]" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="false" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="nosensor" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="[package_name]" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="[package_name].permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the 3 phones involved had enabled Developer Mode; disabling Developer Mode fixed the problem. No idea why, but the causality is definitely there.

Answer (score 0):

This happen in 2 conditions.

Your app is not available in the country from where the user is trying to download or the min Android version of your app is greater than your users mobile android version.

In your case I think its country. Cross check in which countries your app is allowed to download.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! And apologies for not including this data: the user is located in the United States (we're available in the US) and my app's min Android version is 4.0 when the user's devices ship with 6.0. I'll add that information to the post :)

Comment: In your Play store account where you uploaded the app, in Pricing & Distribution tab, how many countries you have selected to distribute your app in?

Comment: It says 136 countries

Comment: Open the list and check is US in that list as well or not?

Comment: Yep, the US is on that list

Comment: change your target sdk to the latest one and try.